# ProgressDialog sometimes get error in asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

it's something weird , sometimes when I come to my activiity , it calls a asyncTask , this is the code where i use ProgressDialog

```
ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog ;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    ringProgressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(Myactivity.this, null,"message", true);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

somedays the asynctask get error ,I wanted to post the error but somehow I don't have the error .

What is the problem of this ?Why it sometimes get error and sometimes it works fine ?
I'm sure the problem is from progressDialog .

Thanks

Comment: reproduce the error and put logcat record here.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog ;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             ringProgressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), null,"message", true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(ringProgressDialog.isShowing())
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it the other way

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching News...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
   public void getDataFromServer(final Context context){

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
            ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog ;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                ringProgressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(context, null,"message", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // write your service call code here
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog("Your Activity");
            pDialog.setMessage("Your message");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
           pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```